# Using just the variable name (not full file path) for inline variable substitution in Model Builder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I am trying to use inline variable substitution in ModelBuilder to return the name of a raster used in Zonal Statistics as a field in my output table (see model below).

Currently, the model works fine using the `"%Raster Dataset%"` to get the field I want, but it returns the FULL file path - e.g. `C/Users/Newton/GIS/Project/RASTER123` instead of just `"RASTER123"`. Anyone know how to just select the name of the input raster, not the full path?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With some help from colleagues and lots of googling I found the answer.

If you choose *"Insert" --> Model only tools --> Parse Path*, and connect the Raster Dataset to this, choose Parse type = Name, and Rename the "Value" output from the ParsePath tool to "RasterName", you will get JUST the Raster name if you change the expression (blue, in jpeg above) to "%RasterName%".